# Is Firefox 6 performance worse in Ubuntu than upstream?

Tags: firefox, performance

It has been said that [Firefox 6 will perform better](http://glandium.org/blog/?p=1975) than previous version because it compiles with a newer version of GCC, version 4.5, and aggressive optimization.

When I updated to Firefox 6 in Natty I read the changelog and wondered whether Firefox 6 really would perform better than previous version *in* Ubuntu because one item in the changelog read (the changelog can be read via `apt-get changelog firefox`):

> Unconditionally build with `--disable-elf-hack`. It's basically a noop
>   on Ubuntu, as we don't get any of the nice space saving and startup
>   time improvements that upstream builds get with it. Enabling it is
>   problematic (it fails to build on all architectures in Ubuntu from
>   Firefox 7 onwards, and is already problematic on armel when building
>   on older Ubuntu versions)

What does this mean? Does it mean that Firefox 6 performance worse in Ubuntu than upstream?

Comment: AFAIK `-O3` and `--disable-elf-hack` are completely different. `-O3` tries hard to optimize the instructions where `--disable-elf-hack` looks like disabling something which should decrease the binary size and thereby saving a few milliseconds.

Comment: @Lekensteyn What you mean by "saving a few milliseconds"? In build time, startup time or application performance?

Comment: In startup time because a smaller image needs to be loaded into memory.

Comment: It seems that only affects the size of the file you need to download and Firefox startup time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Elfhack) for an explanation of the term "elf-hack". It's basically a compile-time linker optimisation.

In the last blog post from that link, JavaScript performance on the dromaeo benchmark is shown to be 0.6% better when firefox is compiled with the elf-hack.

So no, you won't notice any difference in regular use. Improvements in gcc will probably allow use of the 'elf-hack' in 11.10+ anyway.

Comment: What is regular use and what is not?